# How to detect when the keyboard is up in adjust nothing mode?

Tags: android

I want to check when the keyboard is up when `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`.
The [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) didn't work for me in this state.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it to adjustNothing, it's still not possible to detect whether or not the keyboard is visible using his code snippet. To work around this, check this code below.

```
View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        ... do something here
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: This is not being called when you have 'adjustNothing', only first time screen opens